# Swift: Set UITextfieldDelegate on custom TableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, delegates

I'm going nuts on swift...
I got a UITableViewController with a custom UITableViewCell. The UITableView cells contains a UITextfield which is connected through the Interface Builder.

Although I can edit the UITextfield without setting the delegate, I can't make the keyboard disappear. When I try to set the delegate of the UITextField the App crashed with the error.

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Since I set the TextFiled via the IB, I don't have to create it with UITextField(), do I? What am I missing?

MainTableViewController:

```
import UIKit

class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

  // MARK: - Table view data source

  override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 5
  }


  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CounterCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CounterTableViewCell
    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
  }  
}
```

Custom TableViewCell:

```
import UIKit

class CounterTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

  // ==================================================
  // MARK: - Variables

  // ==================================================
  // MARK: - Outlets & Actions
  @IBOutlet weak var tfName: UITextField!

  // ==================================================
  // MARK: - Lifecycle
  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    NSLog("init coder")

    // ERROR HERE: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
    tfName.delegate = self
  }

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
  }

  // ==================================================
  // MARK: - UITableViewCell methods
  override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
  }

  // MARK: - UITextFieldDelegate
  func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
  }

  func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    return true;
  }

  func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    // do nothing yet
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're creating the text field in Interface Builder, why don't you connect the `delegate` property there too? Just control-drag from the text field to your view controller and select **delegate** from the popup menu.

You can't set the text field's delegate in `init(coder:)`, because at that point the text field hasn't been unarchived yet. If you want to set this programmatically, try doing it in `awakeFromNib`, which is guaranteed to be called *after* all the objects in the nib have been unarchived.